# Error: Cannot find module './api/routers'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, next.js

## Hi,

**Hope all of you are doing well...**

I am trying to developer a NextJS single page web application. For nextJs custom server I'm using Express, MongoDB, Also, using nodemon for hot reload.
If I start the server it's showing error (Error: Cannot find module './api/routers') module not found and finally app crashed. But I created the api/routers folder and file Also, created and export express router function.

```js
const router = require("express").Router();

router.get("/all", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: 'It's working...' });
})

module.exports = router;
```

Please tale a look my folder structure and server setup in below.
Have anything wrong in server setup that I made?

Please help me to know @all, expert developer.

```js
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
const dev = process.env.NODE_DEV !== 'production' //true false
const nextApp = next({ dev })
const handle = nextApp.getRequestHandler() //part of next config

const db = require("mongoose")
const routers = require("./api/routers")

// const mongoose = require("mongoose")
// const db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Profile',{ useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true })

const db_uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/profile"


nextApp.prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const app = express()
    app.use(bodyParser.json())
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

    app.use('/api', routers)

    app.all('*', (req, res) => {
      return handle(req, res)
    })
    app.listen(port, err => {
      if (err) {
        throw err
      } else {
        db.connect(db_uri,
          { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true }, () => {
            console.log("Database Connected...");
            console.log(`> Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`)
          })
      }
    })
  })
  .catch((ex) => {
    console.error(ex.stack);
    process.exit(1);
  })
```

## Please take a look folder structure & nodemon json setup here

[image: Folder structure]

## Also error in console

[image: console error]

Comment: I think you need to import the routers file specifically, like this ```require('./api/routers/routers')```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
const dev = process.env.NODE_DEV !== 'production' //true false
const nextApp = next({ dev })
const handle = nextApp.getRequestHandler() //part of next config

const db = require("mongoose")
const routers = require("./api/routers") // there's no index.js

// const mongoose = require("mongoose")
// const db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Profile',{ useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true })

const db_uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/profile"


nextApp.prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const app = express()
    app.use(bodyParser.json())
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

    app.use('/api', routers)

    app.all('*', (req, res) => {
      return handle(req, res)
    })
    app.listen(port, err => {
      if (err) {
        throw err
      } else {
        db.connect(db_uri,
          { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true }, () => {
            console.log("Database Connected...");
            console.log(`> Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`)
          })
      }
    })
  })
  .catch((ex) => {
    console.error(ex.stack);
    process.exit(1);
  })
```

By default require will assume there's an index.js file if it can't find a module, allowing for the ability to import as `./api/routers`, your referencing a directory that doesn't include an index.js(x).

Either directly reference `./api/routers/router` or create an index file.

EDIT: index.jsx lives inside your server/api directory, there's no need for the extra `./api`, otherwise it'd actually look like: `./server/api/api/routers/router`, which isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: @AsMdHabibullah can you add the contents of your routers.jsx to your original answer please

Comment: Sure,


const routers = require("express").Router();

routers.get("/all", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ hello: 'world' });
})

module.exports = routers;

Comment: I can't believe I missed that, sorry, the path needs to be `./routers/router`, not `./api/routers/router`. I'll update my original answer.

Comment: It's not like your given path. Same issue and now saying path not found.

Comment: It's hard to tell what path index.jsx lives at, try explicitly referencing the extension so /api/routers/router.jsx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213594/discussion-between-as-md-habibullah-and-isolated).

Comment: I changed all of my server setup and now it's working...
Thank you developer.

Answer (score 0):

this won't work because you're trying to import a folder not the file that contains these routes

```
const routers = require("./api/routers")
```

try this

```
const routers = require("./api/routers/router")
```

Comment: I changed router.jsx file to index.jsx but it's didn't work.

Comment: what about the answer I wrote did you try that? @AsMdHabibullah

Comment: Already I tried like this--> const routers = require("./api/routers/router")
It's also not working. Same error, module not found.

Comment: try converting router file to .js file

Comment: I changed all of my server setup and now it's working...
Thank you developer.